How to activate a nested, named router outlet
Starting on a fresh Angular 17 project (+SSR/SCSS but shouldn't have any impact on the issue), this is my bootstrapped app.component.html with the default outlet:
<h1>App Component</h1>
<router-outlet />

And this is the child.component.html with the nested, named outlet:
<p>childcomponent works!</p>
<router-outlet name="userProfile"></router-outlet>

A third "demo" component should be rendered in this named outlet. This is my router setup:
export const routes: Routes = [{
  path: "demo",
  component: DemoComponent,
  outlet: "userProfile"
}, {
  path: "global/en",
  component: ChildComponent,
}];

I can call localhost:4200/global/en(userProfile:demo) without any error message but the DemoComponent is never rendered inside the named outlet. Putting the demo route in the "children" array of the main route doesn't work either. When accessing the nested outlet from the angular dev tools, it throws an "Outlet not activated" error. What am I missing here ?

Because the <router-outlet name="userProfile"> is rendered as part of ChildComponent, the associated routes should be children of the route to ChildComponent.
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'global/en',
    component: ChildComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'demo',
        component: DemoComponent,
        outlet: 'userProfile',
      },
    ],
  },
];

This should solve your "Outlet not activated" error because the ChildComponent is now loaded before the Router tries to find the named outlet to activate the DemoComponent.
The way to route to this component is a little complex. You have to specify the routes for the named outlet in an object passed to the RouterLink binding for the navigation trigger.
<a [routerLink]="['/', 'global', 'en', { outlets: { userProfile: 'demo' }}]"></a>

<!-- OR: -->
<a [routerLink]="['/global/en', { outlets: { userProfile: 'demo' }}]"></a>

Here's a working StackBlitz demo to play around with.
Aside: if possible, you should look into lazy-loading components with loadComponent()/loadChildren() so they're not included in the initial bundle.
